# Not able to create webhooks in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, webhooks

Recently I purchase SSL for facebook webhooks.
In my local its working fine but in live server I am not able to create webhooks.

[Image which i am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebznH.png)

Please need help.

```
  if (isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge'])) {

    $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];

    $verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];


    if ($verify_token === 'a5539a3a27d0d8519ddce158987ffb65') {

        echo $challenge;

    }   

    die();

}
```

Comment: debug your code and see if the challenge actually gets returned/echoed

Answer (score 0):

```
define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'abc');                                    
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];                             

if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' &&       
    $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
  echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}
```